# Making a program with a GUI

Tags: c, user-interface

I'm currently making a program in C which I plan to make a GUI for. At the moment I just want to finish the backend so that it can run fine when using terminal commands and then add the GUI later.

Is this an OK approach or should I try and implement aspects of the GUI from the beginning? I've never made one in C and I only have made one at all before and it was in Java.

Comment: Are you targeting a specific OS?

Comment: If you've never done GUI development, I think your notion of doing the back-end first makes some sense.  While you're working on that, you can experiment with GUI development in a lighter-weight program than your main one.

Comment: It's specifically for linux systems

Comment: What do you think about FLTK or Motif?

Answer (score 0):

Separating the UI from the logic is not only OK, it's even **encouraged.** So go with your current approach.